# libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file.

Tags: oracle, shell, cron, environment-variables

I want to schedule a task on Linux by icrontab, and the task is written in python and have to import `cx_Oracle` module, so I export `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in *.bash_profile*, but
it raise the error:

> libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file.

Since it is ok to run the task by issue the command in shell like:

```
python a.py  # ok
```

I change the task in icrontab into a shell script which invoke my Python script, but the exception recurred?

```
# the shell script scheduled in icrontab
#! bash 
python a.py
```

Could you help how to do with it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possibly you want to specify `PATH` — and also `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` — so that `cron(1)` knows where to find binaries.
Read "5 Crontab environment" [here](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: but we I update the shell script as below:  
#! /bin/bash
echo $ORACLE_HOME
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  
and redirect the output of crontab to log file
why these path have been found and writted to log?

Comment: @zhangzhong I suppose you'd like to use `export` not `echo` ?  

E. g. `export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle10/foo` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/bar`

Answer (score 9):

The libs are located in 
`/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib` (For Oracle XE) or similar.

You should add this path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or if this file shows only an include location, as in a separate file in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory

I have oracle.conf in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, just one file with the path. Nothing else.

Of course don't forget to run ldconfig as a last step.

Comment: what content should "oracle.conf " write?

Answer (score 3):

Cron does not load the user's profile when running a task and you have to include the profile in your shell script explicitly.

[Example documentation](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3):

If you have problem with libclntsh.so, need create symlink for libclntsh.so from `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib` to `/usr/lib`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem last weekend when I needed to use cx_Oracle.  After spending a lot of time trying to modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to include the $ORACLE_HOME/lib directoy, where libclntsh.so resides, I ended up solving the problem by creating symbolic links from all the Oracle xlibx.so libraries into /lib/xlibx.so.  This certainly isn't the "cleanest" solution, but it has a good chance of working without causing too much trouble:

```
 cd $ORACLE_HOME/lib
 for f in `ls ./*.so*`; do;
   sudo ln -s $ORACLE_HOME/lib/$f /lib/$f 
 done
```

After I did that, cx_Oracle worked like a charm.

Comment: I have solved it after including in the script: . ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Where did you include the script from?

Comment: Technically this will work, but it's the wrong answer, since the next time you update the Oracle client this can break (and would need to be re-run).  The better answer is to fix the script that needs Python/Oracle and set the environment values correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This post helped me solve a similar problem with a PostgreSQL database link to Oracle using `oracle_fdw`.

I installed `oracle_fdw` but when I tried `CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw;` I got `error could not load library libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

I checked `$ORACLE_HOME`, `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

It worked only AFTER I put Oracle Shared Library on Linux Shared Library

```
echo /opt/instantclient_11_2 > oracle.conf
ldconfig
```

Comment: where did you output oracle.conf to?

Comment: I suppose it should be `echo /opt/instantclient_11_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the dependency

`oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your Oracle path variables before you run any scripts:
Like for perl you can do add below in beginning of your script:

```
BEGIN {
   my $ORACLE_HOME     = "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
   my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
   if ($ENV{ORACLE_HOME} ne $ORACLE_HOME
   || $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ne $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ) {
      $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}     = "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
      $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
      exec { $^X } $^X, $0, @ARGV;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always have this problem, I can solve by running the code below:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

[image]

OBS: This code I saved in the configuration file because I always use it.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied all library files from installer media *databases/stage/ext/lib* to *$ORACLE_HOME/lib* and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else coming here by far the best thing to do is to update `cx_Oracle` to the latest version (6+).  This version does not need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set at all.

Comment: cx_Oracle 6 always needs the OS library search path configured (e.g. with LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ldconfig) - see the doc.  It was only 5.2 and 5.3 versions that [used RPATH linking](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/python-cxoracle-52-driver-for-oracle-database-has-been-released) and didn't need you to set the library search path.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to `sudo` into an account registered with relevant env settings :)