# R scripts crontab error about Oracle

Tags: r

I am newer but I real get a question : I have one R script to put in crontab and get one error,but I can run the scripts in commandline.the error is :

```html
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/RRO-8.0.1/R-3.1.2/lib64/R/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Loading required package: plyr
Loading required package: lubridate

Attaching package: 'lubridate'

The following object is masked from 'package:plyr':

    here

Loading required package: mailR
Error: Couldn't find driver Oracle. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called Oracle
* in package called ROracle
```

some tips will be very thanks

Comment: It's more a Linux problem than a R problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708317/libclntsh-so-11-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: I just add . /etc/profile;   in the crontab  and it works  ~

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same error while running in crontab as all env variables are not correctly set when run through crontab. You can either define variables ORACLE_HOME,LD_LIBRARY_PATH,PATH in the crontab before r script or simply use shell wrapper to call the r script. By default all env variables are read and set properly in shell and you can call the r scipt from there.

Comment: This is a great solution. To build on this for those using the `cronR` package to manage their cron jobs: these environmental variables can be specified using the parameter `env = Sys.getenv()[c("ORACLE_HOME", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "OCI_LIB", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64")]` when calling `cronR::cron_add`.